# Search if a word is inside an array

Tags: javascript

I have this script and would like to make it search if just the word Mango is in the array and if it is true console.log the index of it.

I have tried the code below, but it always fail(false).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <h1>Array includes()</h1>
    <p>Check if the fruit array contains "Mango":</p>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <p><strong>Note:</strong> The includes method is not supported in Edge 13 (and earlier versions).</p>
    <script>
        var fruits = ["Banana is yellow", "Orange juice", "Apple is red", "Mango is orange"];
        var n = fruits.includes("Mango");
        console.log(n);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I need it to return what is the index where it is located = 4

Comment: Includes returns the boolean.

Comment: Why `.includes()` is not the right tool -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes (solution in the ["See also"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#See_also) section on the same site)

Answer (score 6):

You want to *find the index* were the string *includes* a substring:

```
  fruits.findIndex(fruit => fruit.includes("Mango"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try  this:

```js
const fruits = ["Banana is yellow", "Orange juice", "Apple is red", "Mango is orange"];
const getIndex = srch => fruits.findIndex(ele => ele.indexOf(srch)>-1);

console.log(getIndex("Mango"))
```

Answer (score 1):

In case if you have to support IE (findIndex is not supported by IE) you can use smth like this:

```
var fruits = ["Banana is yellow", "Orange juice", "Apple is red", "Mango is orange"];
var index;
fruits.forEach((el, i) => {
    if(el.toLowerCase().indexOf('Mango'.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        index = i;
    }
});
console.log(index);
```